# Firebase: using DocumentSnapshot id as User uid. Thoughts?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Currently users profiles are created by adding a user to a firestore collection.

I then have an onCreate function that will create a user in Firebase Authentication.

Would there be an issue with using the firestore docId as the created users uid?

Thanks

```js
export const createUser = functions.region('europe-west2')
    .firestore.document('users/{user}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) =>
        executeOnce(context.eventId, async (transaction: FirebaseFirestore.Transaction) => {
            const data = snap.data();

            await auth.createUser({
                uid: snap.id,
                email: data.email,
                password: //,
                displayName: `${data.firstName} ${data.lastName}`,
            }).then(async function (newUser) {
                return db.collection('users').doc(snap.id)
                    .update({
                        status: 'Active',
                    });
            }).catch(function (error) {
                return console.error(`Error creating user, ${error}`);
            });

        }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why that would be an issue. Usually UID from Firebase Authentication is used as Firestore document ID. It's just an identifier so you can accurately point at the document containing current user's information. (<= just an example)

```
const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid)
```

At the end, it's just a unique string. So as long as they both are same, you should be fine. Even if they are not, you could still query Firestore document using `.where("userId", "==", uid)`.